# .Net ASMX Web Service - SoapException not understood by client?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have a .Net web service which is consumed by a Xamarin Android app. Sometimes an error occurs in the web service and I would like this to be shown to the client app.

I have used this code in the web service:

```
Catch ex As Exception
  Throw New SoapException("Failed", SoapException.ServerFaultCode)
End Try
```

Then in Xamarin I have a Try/Catch around the web service request.

However, I cannot get Android / Xamarin to understand that an exception has occurred. In Fiddler I can see the HTTP Response is 500 and the text "Failed" is sent back. I guess this should infact be a SOAP XML body containing a SoapException instead?

Is there something else I need to do this on either client or web service?

Answer (score 0):

The code catching the exception and throwing a new one.

This results in the following:

- You do not see the real error. The real error is in "ex", but the code does not use any information from ex.
- The Client gets a http 500 response. This is "internal error", that the code has an unhandled exception. The line that starts with "Throw" is causing the http 500 error.